# nextjs router can't pass the value

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i'm working on an ecommerce project with nextJ react. i got the product listed but i want the product details when i click on the product card. i used this code below to pass the params. i still got the same error 404. can someone help me this.

After this code how i should retrieve the info on the productDetails page?

thanks

```
onClick={() =>
          router.push({
            pathname: "/productDetails/[pid]",
            query: { pid: id },
          })
        }
```

Comment: what does your project file structure look like?

Comment: What happens if you pass the url only, like router.push(`/productDetails/${id}`)

Comment: got the same error message

Comment: onClick={() => router.push(`/productDetails/:${id}`)}  the url show me that the id has been pass. http://localhost:3000/productDetails/:2

Comment: [`router.push`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush) signature is as follows: `router.push(url, as, options)`. You need to call it like ``router.push(`/productDetails/${id}`)``. If you still get a 404 that means the page you're trying to route to doesn't exist.